# Запретить переопределение триггеров

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Доброго времени суток, Господа. Возникла нужда сделать SearchBox.
Суть вопроса заключается в следующем:
TextBox + Button я поместил в UserControl. Нужно при наведении мышкой на UserControl изменить Background/Foreground этого UserControl'а и соответственно сделать так, чтобы изменились на эти значения мой TextBox и кнопка. Эту задачу я реализовал. Вот код:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PTRCPriceCalculator.SearchBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PTRCPriceCalculator"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Style="{StaticResource UserControlStyle}"
             d:DesignHeight="40" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">

            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" 
                         Style="{StaticResource DarkTextBox}"
                         Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                         Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                         Text="Search..."/>

                <Button Grid.Column="1" 
                        Style="{StaticResource InnerSearchButton}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
            </Grid>  
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>  
</UserControl>
```

Вот стиль UserControl'а:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}" x:Key="UserControlStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundMediumDarkBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundLightBrush}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundDarkBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundVeryLightBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

А вопрос заключается в том, что мне нужно, чтобы если пользователь наводит мышкой конкретно на кнопку, то у нее изменять свойства Background/Foreground по другому, уникально. Но дело в том, что мой триггер UserControl'а переопределяет триггер кнопки, и соответственно когда я навожу мышкой на кнопку, то ничего уникального не происходит.

Не подскажите, как решить проблему?

Вот стиль InnerSearchButton:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>

<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundVeryDarkBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: «мой триггер UserControl'а переопределяет триггер кнопки» — а где в вашем коде триггер на кнопке? Покажите лучше стиль `InnerSearchButton`.

Comment: А как в комментарии код скинуть? Он же многострочный. Да там стиль довольно простой

Comment: @Bretbas можно например gist.github использовать

Comment: @Bretbas: Код должен быть в вопросе. Отредактируйте вопрос, там есть ссылка «править».

Comment: Все, я поправил мой вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в порядке применения значений [dependency property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence). Локально заданное значение (№3 в списке) всегда сильнее значения, определённого в стиле (№8 в списке) и триггеров стиля (№6 в списке).

Так что `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"` перекрывает значения из стиля. Поэтому вам нужно не задавать `Background` явно, а создать производный стиль, в котором добавить нужные сеттеры.

Comment: Я бы хотел сделать так: У меня есть SearchBox, в котором есть внутренняя кнопка. Нужно сделать, чтобы я мог применять разные стили для SearchBox в целом, но внутри этого стиля, можно было определять стиль для кнопки, чтобы он был как бы тоже внутреннем

Comment: @Bretbas: Я попробую написать позже, когда будет время.

Comment: @Bretbas: Посмотрите сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752780/10105